# Quartz Plugin - No signature of method: .schedule() is applicable for argument types: (Long, Integer, LinkedHashMap)

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I'm developing an app in Grails 2.1.3 and need to be able to dynamically schedule a job. I am having an issue with the MyJob.schedule() method from the [Quartz Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/quartz) version 1.0.1.

Currently I have code calling the job which appears as:

```
MyJob.schedule((Long)thing.processInterval,-1,[keyName:thing.value])
```

With the MyJob class looking like:

```
package com.a.b.jobs
import com.a.b.thing.ThingsService

class MyJob{

    static triggers = {}

    def ThingsService 

    def execute(context) {
        def scheduledThing = ThingsService.getInstance(context.mergedJobDataMap.get('keyName'))
        //Do things
        scheduledThing.dateProcessed = new Date()
    }
}
```

The error I am now seeing is:

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.a.b.jobs.MyJob.schedule() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Long, java.lang.Integer, java.util.LinkedHashMap)

But as per http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-quartz/guide/triggers.html this should be an acceptable call.

I have followed guidance given by [this post](http://blogs.quovantis.com/shalvika/2012/04/scheduling-jobs-dynamically-with-grails/) to import the package containing the job class but not the job class itself

```
import com.a.b.jobs.*;
```

vs

```
import com.a.b.jobs.MyJob;
```

but this has not solved my problem.

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Edited to add unit test && service.

```
package com.a.b.thing

import spock.lang.Specification
import com.a.b.thing.Thing

@TestFor(JobStartService)
@Mock([Thing])
@TestMixin(grails.test.mixin.support.GrailsUnitTestMixin)
class JobStartServiceSpec extends Specification {
    def "test schedule"() {
        when:
            def myThing = new Thing()
            myThing.processInterval = 1
            myThing.name = "name"
            myThing.save(failOnError:true)
            assert Thing.findAll().size() == 1
            service.startJobs()

        then: "the returned Thing has been processed"
            assert myThing.dateProcessed != null

    }
}


//service
package com.a.b.thing

import groovy.time.*
import com.a.b.jobs.*;

class JobStartService {

    def thingsService

    def startJobs(){
        Thing.findAll().each{
            if(!it.dateProcessed){
                MyJob.schedule(((Long)it.processInterval), -1,[keyName:it.value])
            }else {
                //other stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you have the job class in the project? When do you get this error?

Comment: It is located in grails-app/jobs/com/a/b/jobs/MyJob.groovy, and I get this error during unit testing of the service using .schedule().

Comment: Can you also add the unit test case?

Comment: Added Unit Test case and Service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **schedule** method is metaClass magic. In order to unit test dynamic job scheduling, the easiest thing to do is to make your own magic:

```
given:
def isScheduled = false
MyJob.metaClass.static.schedule = { Long repeatInterval, Integer repeatCount, Map params -> 
     isScheduled = true 
}
```

...

```
when:
service.startJobs()


then:
isScheduled
```